# Scala. Sets as functions

Tags: scala, set

I have a problem. I'm representing a set by its characterisitc function, so I've defined a type alias for this representation. The function filterHead should take a set and a predicate as an input and return a result of function f .

```
 type Set = Int => Boolean
 def filterHead(s: Set, f: Int => Boolean): Boolean = f(s.head)
```

Then the following error occures: "value head is not a member of Int => Boolean". And the error related to type allias definition, not to input function f

Comment: In the snippet above, the `s : Set` is essentially `s : Int => Boolean`, because you've defined an alias for `Set`. It's not referring to a 'collection' set, so there's no `head` to begin with...

Comment: but worksheet gives this output
`val set = Set(1,2,3)`                   
`set.head  //> res2: Int = 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define the alias for `Set`, the `Set` parameter will be 'unrolled' to the full type:

```
scala> type Set = Int => Boolean
defined type alias Set

scala> def foo(s : Set, i : Int) = ???
foo: (s: Int => Boolean, i: Int)Nothing
```

And when you're using the `Set(1,2,3)`, you're using the companion object's `apply` method which returns a different type:

```
scala> val set = Set(4,1,2)
set: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(4, 1, 2)
```

Also, as you might notice, the collection set is generic here. You could make a generic type alias too though (the alias would be `Set[T]`), so there still could be some confusion.

Solution? Use a full type name:

```
scala> def filterHead(s : scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int], setFunc : Set) = setFunc(s.head)
filterHead: (s: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int], setFunc: Int => Boolean)Boolean
```

Or give your alias a different name:

```
type SetFunc = Int => Boolean
```

or, in a generic way:

```
type SetFunc[T] = T => Boolean
```

Or even import the `scala.collection.immutable.Set[T]` under a different name - alias on import.